# Arduino LED Cube 8x8x8 with a Led Driver (TLC5940NT)

Tags: arduino, led, driver

Me and a group of friends need to make a college project and decided to do a LED cube that can graph mathematical functions. We do not know how to code very well, and are very new to Electrical Engineering. We decided that we are gonna build the cube using an Arduino Uno. After searching quite a few cubes decided to build this:

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-build-an-8x8x8-LED-cube-and-control-it-with/?ALLSTEPS

We choose this one because its very easy to build, and doesn't have a bunch of components we don't know (and especially, aren't available in our city). Problem is the A6276 LED drivers are discontinued. We want to try building the cube using the TLC5940, which we already have. Problems is, we don't understand the new features of the TLC5940, and after reading many times the datasheets we still don't know if we can use the TLC LED drivers instead of the A6276. So I am asking how can we use the TLC5940 to make a multiplexing 8x8x8 LED Cube using Arduino Uno.

I know there are many guides to do LED cubes, and many include Arduino in them, but there are only a few for big LED cubes, and even fewer guides with the simplicity like the one we choose. And I couldn't find an 8x8x8 guide that used the TLC5940. Please, help me, our heads are melting trying to find a solution!

Datasheets:
(Cant post 3 links, but search for TLC5940 datasheet, first result.)
[http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A6276-Datasheet.ashx](http://www.allegromicro.com/%7E/media/Files/Datasheets/A6276-Datasheet.ashx)

The cube will be built using single color 5mm LEDs.

Comment: FTR, the '5940 melted my head too, at first.

Answer (score 1):

The TLC5940 is overkill for this. It has PWM dimming of the LEDs, which will actually make it *harder* to implement.

The [TLC59284](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc59284) appears to be both pin- and signal-compatible with the A6276, and should be considered for use instead.